# Is it possible to use the native filebrowser to pick a file stored on the server?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two usecases, first, users can pick a local file and upload it to the server. Second, users can pick a file that is already on the server (uploaded, emailed etc by them). I know there are lots of libraries that do this, but Is it possible to use the native file browser, and allow them to pick a file, stored on the server, using that? It's okay if all browsers are not supported.

Comment: There's [this old article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567369/reading-server-side-file-with-javascript) that maybe can help you ;) Cheers.

Comment: Do not believe it is possible for `<input type="file">` dialog to reference filesystem other than users local filesystem

Comment: What end result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Gorka That approach should work, where uploaded `file.name`s are stored in an array or object locally and same file name is stored at server; populate `<select>` element with with `<option>` elements having `file.name` as `value`, at `change` event of `select` use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` to retrieve `option` value from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not believe it is possible for `<input type="file">` dialog to reference filesystem other than users local filesystem.

> It's okay if all browsers are not supported

A workaround would be to save names or references of uploaded files at an array or object, save actual uploaded file at `FileSystem` using `requestFileSystem`, provide user with list of uploaded files, when user selects file from list, retrieve `File` object from `FileSystem` using `requestFileSystem`.

See [jQuery File Upload Plugin: Is possible to preserve the structure of uploaded folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106121/jquery-file-upload-plugin-is-possible-to-preserve-the-structure-of-uploaded-fol/37107246#37107246)

---

Alternatively, as suggested by @Gorka, you can store uploaded `file.name`s in an array or object locally where uploaded `file` object is stored at server same file name; populate `<select>` element with with `<option>`elements having `file.name` as `value`; at change event of `select` element use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` to retrieve selected `<option>` `value` from server. For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" />
  <select disabled>
    <option>Choose File from server</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <label></label>
  <br>
  <iframe style="width:95vw;height:98vw"></iframe>
  <script>
    var input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
    var select = document.querySelector("select");
    var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
    var label = document.querySelector("label");
    var uploads = [];
    select.onchange = function(e) {
      var uploadedFile = uploads.filter(function(file) {
        return file.name === e.target.value;
      }).pop();

      var url = "/uploads/" + uploadedFile.name;

      fetch(url)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.blob()
        })
        .then(function(file) {
          // do stuff with `file`
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            iframe.onload = function() {
              label.textContent = url;
            }
            iframe.src = e.target.result;
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        })
    }

    input.onchange = function(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      // save reference to uploaded file name
      uploads.push({
        name: file.name,
      });
      // post file to server
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", file, file.name);
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "/path/to/server");
      request.onload = function() {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = file.name;
        option.textContent = file.name;
        select.appendChild(option);
        if (select.disabled) {
          select.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
        alert(`${file.name} written to server`);
      }
      // save `file` as `file.name` at server,
      // for example, at `/uploads/${file.name}`
      request.send(data);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/McvuErPOxyNJcpIZXl1G?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The file browser is controlled by the browser and OS and you cannot make anything about which folder to show.